# Respiratory rate monitor

Tags: operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, thermistor, wheatstone-bridge

I have this project to build an instrumentation system to measure the respiratory rate.

We decided to use a thermistor to measure the variation on the temperature of the air inhaled and exhaled. To measure the variation on the thermistor resistance we decided to use a Wheatsone bridge as shown below.

Since the variation was pretty small (the temperature varies between 25ºC and 28ºC) we needed to amplify the signal. For that we thought about using an instrumentation amplifier - INA128. However it wasn't available in the simulator we were using (which is TINA-TI) so we built the equivalent circuit.

I wanted to know if this is a good option to aquire and amplify this signal, and if this circuit is correct.

[image]

To be able to simulate the signal, we measured the signals on the points that were connected to the opamps, and used voltage sources with similar signals.

[image]

As you can see, the output has a DC component.

I wanted to know if there is something wrong with our Wheatstone bridge that could be causing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not apply power rails to op-amps like you have done: -

[image]

Each op-amp power pin needs a voltage relative to ground or 0 volts. So you apply a positive voltage to one power pin relative to 0 volts and a negative voltage on the other power pin relative to 0 volts. Like this: -

[image]

- Also make sure that your op-amp model can work with voltages as low as those you are indicating.
- Also make sure that your op-amp's input common mode range is sufficient for the power rail voltages you are using
- Also ensure that the op-amp's output voltage range is adequate for the power rails you are using.

Comment: Thank you! I've corrected that. But regardind the rest of the circuit you think it is correct?

Comment: @Catarina does the simulation show it operates as you expected it to now? The circuit does look like a three op-amp configuration that acts like an InAmp if that's what you need to know.

Comment: I think so. Its just that I was reluctant if the wheatstone configuration was indeed correct

Comment: It certainly looks like a correctly monitored wheatstone bridge.

Comment: Is there any way i can have 0 volts on the wheatstone bridge for a reference temperature (for example 25ºC)? Or is it better to just use a filter to remove the DC component?

Comment: @Catarina the normal way is to apply an offset voltage into R7 so, where you have R7 connected to ground, connect it instead to a voltage source and adjust the voltage source until you get the desired output.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to do that